# UITableView Moverows crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am rather new to objective-c and i have some experience with programming.So my problem is the following:

i am using

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
    toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath

{

    NSString *item = [test objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];

    [test removeObject:item];

    [test insertObject:item atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

}
```

so that i can move the rows when in editing style.When the objects in the test array are unique everything works ok.But when 2 or more objects are the same the app crashes.For example if the Strings in the array are : @"BOB" , @"LINDA" , "JOHN" , the i can move the rows just fine.But when the Strings are : @"BOB", @"LINDA" , @"JOHN" , @"BOB" , "@BOB" the app crashes

with the following cause:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (1)'

Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding the item first and then removing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address of a string with the same characters should be the same (constant pointer), so if you remove one item @"BOB" you probably remove both of them from the array if there is another string @"BOB" in it.

I would rather use the `removeObjectAtIndex` function than the object related remove function, and adjust the insert into index path by -1 if necessary (if the to index path lies behind the from index path).

**Note**:

I just did a small test and indeed removing @"BOB" from an array with two times this string removes both strings.

Comment: Thank you both!removeObjectAtIndex did the trick!Nice having people with knowledge ready to help!Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `insertObject:atIndex:` you must ensure that index, for inserting object, is not greater than or equal `[array count]`, otherwise you must use `[array addObject:item]`

Try something like:

```
NSString *item = [test objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
[test removeObject:item];
if ([toIndexPath row] < [test count]) {
    [test insertObject:item atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
}
else {
    [test addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yes did understand that,but how come it works when the objects are different but crashes when the objects are the same?

Comment: Instead `[test removeObject:item]`, try to use `[test removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]]`

Comment: Thank you both!removeObjectAtIndex did the trick!Nice having people with knowledge ready to help!Thank you guys.